# ffmpeg - No NVENC capable devices found

Tags: ffmpeg, nvidia-graphics-card

I am having difficulties in using the NVEnc capabilities of my RTX2070 on a Windows 10 machine. I've used "media-autobuild_suite" to compile FFmpeg and other libraries for my machine.

I've updated my drivers to version 431.70 and I've also installed CUDA Toolkit 10.1

hevc_nvenc is working fine

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -i output/frames/%6d.png -c:v h264_nvenc -preset slow -tune animation -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

But h264_nvenc is throwing the below error

`No NVENC capable devices found.`

Comment: Show the full log (and don't crosspost).